# GTK window stalling when using windows' Sleep()

Tags: c, windows, sleep, gtk

I made a small app that illustrates Quicksort and I have a second window that displays the current array being sorted per level. I was asked to put some sort of delay, and so I opted to use Sleep() of windows.h. However, for some reason the window is stalling and only starts to work *after* the whole thing. Nothing gets displayed per level like I intend to. It works when without Sleep().

It's just a basic quicksort where I put the Sleep() right after the printing mechanism which is both inserted somewhere within the base case bracket.

How to I invoke some sort of pause mechanism without resulting to brute looping?

Answer (score 4):

GTK+ is not multi-threaded. If you stop your process with `Sleep()`, then of course the UI is not going to update since the process is no longer doing the work to run GTK+, it's stuck in `Sleep()`.

The proper fix is probably to make it more event-oriented, so that you take a step in the sorting algorithm as a response to an event. You can use e.g. `g_timeout_add()` to source events, which could just be simple function calls directly into your code.

Comment: But wouldn't the window at least update at some point after sleep?

Answer (score 1):

Your sleep call is probably in the main event loop, causing the overall application to hang. Without source it is difficult to tell you where to put the sleep to make the UI responsive, yet the sorting 'slow'